# I am making a password generator using javascript.The password does not display after being generated

Tags: javascript, passwords, append, textarea

i have been using console.log()'s to make sure that my code is working each step of the way so far, but the password isn't being displayed in the textarea like it should after it's generated. Any help would be great.

```
//javascript
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

var specialCharacters = [
  '@',
  '%',
  '+',
  '\\',
  '/',
  "'",
  '!',
  '#',
  '$',
  '^',
  '?',
  ':',
  ',',
  ')',
  '(',
  '}',
  '{',
  ']',
  '[',
  '~',
  '-',
  '_',
  '.'
];

var upperCasedCharacters = [
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D',
  'E',
  'F',
  'G',
  'H',
  'I',
  'J',
  'K',
  'L',
  'M',
  'N',
  'O',
  'P',
  'Q',
  'R',
  'S',
  'T',
  'U',
  'V',
  'W',
  'X',
  'Y',
  'Z'
];

var lowerCasedCharacters = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'f',
  'g',
  'h',
  'i',
  'j',
  'k',
  'l',
  'm',
  'n',
  'o',
  'p',
  'q',
  'r',
  's',
  't',
  'u',
  'v',
  'w',
  'x',
  'y',
  'z'
];

var numericCharacters = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

var selectedCharacters = [];


// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
 
  passwordText.value = password;

  //prompt for password length
  var passwordLength = prompt("Select a password length between 8 and 128");
        
      //logic to ensure correct length selected
    if (passwordLength >=8 && passwordLength <=128) {

        console.log(passwordLength);
```

this console log is pretty obvious, just to make sure the value is being read

```
          //prompts for selecting character type
        var LC = confirm("Use Lower case characters?");
        var UC = confirm("Use Upper case characters?");
        var N = confirm("Use Numeric characters?");
        var SC = confirm("Use Special characters?");

            //code to make sure a character is selected
          if (LC == true || UC == true || N == true || SC == true){

              if (LC == true) {
                selectedCharacters += lowerCasedCharacters;
              }

              if (UC == true) {
                selectedCharacters += upperCasedCharacters;
              }

              if (N == true) {
                selectedCharacters += numericCharacters;
              }

              if (SC == true) {
                selectedCharacters += specialCharacters;
              }
            
            console.log(selectedCharacters);
```

this console log shows the contents of the selectedChars array to confirm that the user selections were being updated correctly

```
            generatePassword(passwordLength);

          }
        
          else {
            alert("Please select at least one character type");
          }
          
    } 
        
        //error message if incorrect values entered
    else {
      alert("Please enter a value between 8 and 128");
    }
}

function generatePassword(length) {
  var result           = '';
  var characters       = selectedCharacters;
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
     result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}       

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

At this point i have the console log return a a random sequence of characters from the created array as intended, but they dont get posted into the text area

Answer (score 1):

You never set the value of the text field to your generated password.
Assuming you're using jQuery and your text field id is 'passwd' you can do the following:

```
$("#passwd").val(generatePassword(passwordLength));
```

Or if you want to stick to javascript you could use:

```
document.getElementById("passwd").value = generatePassword(passwordLength);
```